# Holepunching of header in magento store

Tags: magento

I have implemented holepunching of header in magento, and even though I have got it working on a per customer basis, I need the ability to take this one level deeper by making it work on diff cart item counts too.

Here is my code.

```
class AD_PageCache_Model_Container_Header extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract {

    protected function _getIdentifier() {
        return $this->_getCookieValue(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CUSTOMER, '');
    }

    // public function getCacheKeyInfo() {
    //  $info = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    //  die('boo');
    //  $info['cart_count'] = Mage::helper( 'checkout/cart' )->getCart()->getItemsCount();

    //  return $info;
    // }

    protected function _getCacheId() {
        //return 'CONTAINER_HEADER_' . md5($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cart_count') ) . '_' . $this->_getIdentifier();
        return 'CONTAINER_HEADER_' . md5( $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . $this->_getIdentifier() );
    }

    protected function _renderBlock() {
        $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
        $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

        $block = new $blockClass;
        $block->setTemplate($template);
        return $block->toHtml();
    }

}
```

My understanding from what I have been reading from holepunching threads on Magento is that Mage app is not initialized when FPC cache is serving the request, so basically the method of adding a placeholder attribute can't work, since `Mage::helper( 'checkout/cart' )->getCart()->getItemsCount();` won't work, right?

And even though how is that it should be, but it didn't seem to run at all, like I placed a `die()` call in there but nothing happened.

So what I am missing? And how can I retrieve the cart items count so that it can be used to build the cache ID?

Progress: I found `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CART` but this changes only once upon cart updation. After that it stays same. This is weird, this feels like the solution but its  behavior says otherwise.

I couldn't find cart items count in session either. So the only way I currently see to do this would be to save the cart quantity in session whenever it updates and then use that in `_getIdentifier()`.

I found that observers are inconsistent for cart. For addition, updation the events are dispatched but for removal, it doesn't. So I guess I can add my observer to price updation of the quote somehow, if that is consistent in having observers?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what is your problem exactly. At first you should return needed data from your block `getCacheKeyInfo()` method and then in `_getCacheId()` of your placeholder class build unique key (i.e. container individual cache id).

Answer (score 0):

See my similar question: [Full Page Cache invalidation on cart (quote) change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802663/full-page-cache-invalidation-on-cart-quote-change)

I gave up on implementing because it wasn't possible in my case, but I'd dig into `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Advanced_Quote` further as it seems to be used by cart block to refresh itself in case of quote contents change

Comment: It handles using `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CART` which doesn't work well in my case, although I think the problem lies inside it. What/How? I am not sure. Also the current version of EE we have running doesn't even have Advanced folder under `Model/Container`.

Comment: @Ashfame are you running EE 1.11?

Comment: Yeah current version is `EE 1.10.1.1`. Our upgrade plan is due for coming weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your idea of saving this to the session is actually a really good one and most likely to work reliably