# Magento: Enterprise Full Page Cache - Disable Cookies / $_COOKIE

Tags: magento, caching, cookies

We have a customised process that relies on a cookie to render some pivotal display options. This is the only real solution as is required for all website guests.

Process works beautifully with FPC disabled, but with it enabled the PHP global $_COOKIE is cached for the entire browser session.

Essentially - we need to apply a patch to FPC to make it ignore cookies (either all or by name - either is fine for now).

Appreciate if anyone has had any success in achieving something similar, or a suitable place to start.

Note: running EE1.12 on AWS nginx build.

Cheers,
t8

Answer (score 0):

In FPC with no Dynamic Block Magento application initialization is not done.
So as you want some part of your page to vary depending on Cookies you need to use Dynamic Block.

For this you will have to create a container class and set lifetime as Null as in snippet below

1.Try adding this to your container class: protected function _saveCache($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifetime = null) { return false; } That should prevent it from getting cached.

Also this link on Stackoverflow :
[How do I include a dynamic block in the product page with full page caching turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn)

details out on Dynamic Blocks and FPC.