# Proper way to display cart quantity

Tags: magento

I'm running into issues when displaying the cart quantity in the header. I'm simply useing `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()`. It works great *sometimes*, however it does not display correctly on the front page. I have a feeling that it's related to our full page caching.

I reached out to Magento support and they said that I am doing it different from how they would. But would not provide me with an answer.

Can anyone shed some light on the correct method for displaying cart quantity?

Comment: What full page caching are you using and have you set the block containing the cart quantity to be excluded from caching?

Comment: @JonathanHussey I believe it's simply the built in Magento Full Page caching. What's odd is that my code works on every page, except for the home page. I have added the count to links.phtml. And no, I have not excluded it from caching.

Comment: Ok so we are talking about EE rather than CE?

Comment: @JonathanHussey Correct, EE. I looked around and came across `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty()`. Gave it a shot, and it's doing the same thing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well the core logic uses `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()` as you have above so I don't have any reason to believe that shouldn't return the correct value.  How does behaviour change if you disable full page caching?

Comment: For a dynamic part you need to create a container and exclude it from FPC.It look slike with your home page this has not been done.

Comment: @SatishMantri any recommendations / resources that you can provide? Anything would be helpful.

Comment: Did you switch off Full Page Caching plus deleted cache from var folder and checked.Also is there any other caching module in place.

Comment: If disabling FPC results in this problem gone then you need to create containers and exclude this container from getting cached.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn/9125519#9125519  will be of great help in case your issue is related to FPC

Comment: @SatishMantri Full page caching disabled, and the full_page_cache directory has been emptied. Problem still persists. No quantity on home page.

Comment: make sure session is not lost when on Home page.Are other session related values if any, available on home page.

Comment: $result=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); Mage::log($result); Do this and check whats goes into mage Log file.There is a probability that the block code you are looking at and the code responsible and generatin output are different.